# ajax promise data undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm somewhat breaking my head over this. I have an ajax call like this:

```
function genericname()
{
    var domain = $('#input').val();
    var sendData = {
        'domain': domain
    };

    var promise = $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/functions.php',
        data:
        {
            module: 'modulename',
            operation: 'functionname',
            parameters: sendData
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).promise();

    promise.then(function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });

    promise.fail(function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Now the problem is that when debugging I notice that both promise.then and promise.fail are just skipped. The php proces I am calling to output is true. Actually when I look in the network tab of the debug tools the response says true.

Could anyone explain what the mistake is here?

EDIT: the result being output by the php function is json_encoded

This function is being called in the .then portion of another ajax call

Comment: loose the .promise() at the end of ajax call. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The code works in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg20b8d7/2/), with and without the call to promise();. To continue using the data returned by `promise.then()`, you'd need to return that from `genericname()` --> https://jsfiddle.net/yg20b8d7/3/ - return `promise.then(...);` or more sensible, simply return the `promise` and chain `then` to `genericname`

Answer (score 1):

remove .promise at the end of ajax request:

```
var domain = $('#input').val();
var sendData = {
    'domain': domain
};

var promise = $.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/functions.php',
    data:
    {
        module: 'modulename',
        operation: 'functionname',
        parameters: sendData
    },
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Comment: that didn't seem to fix it. I will add something important I forogt to the question though

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed now and here is how I solved it.

The function was required to return a boolean which was used in the if statement in another .then statement of another ajax call to change some html.
In the end I resorted to placing the html changes in the .then portion if this function.

Hope I can help someone with this information.